# where is the app folder it talks about in the instructions for installing express for node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, directory

I know this sounds like a stupid question. But I am trying to install express for node.js. I am very disappointed there is no nice installer gui. Instead I am forced to use a tacky command line. I live in the 21st centuary and I am forced to mess about with some shoddy command line.

and the instructions are too concise, so I can not make proper sense of them.

Does anyone know where this folder is: "Now install Express in the app directory and save it in the dependencies list. For example:"

It talks about it on the instructions page

http://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

The reason I ask is because I am trying to locate express for a netbeans project which says "express must be selected" in the project creating wizard and the folder path is empty.

build my own static file server instead: no need for frameworks now :)!

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var url = require('url');
var allowedFolders = {'./scripts': true, './styles': true, './images': true};
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log('got request main');
    var requestUrl = url.parse(request.url);
    var filePath = '.' + requestUrl.pathname;
    if (filePath == './')
    {
        var html = buildHtml(request);
        response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
            'Content-Length': html.length,
            'Expires': new Date().toUTCString()
        });
        response.end(html);
    } 
    else
    {
        if (allowedFolders[path.dirname(filePath)])
        {
            var extname = path.extname(filePath);
            var contentType = 'text/html';
            switch (extname) {
                case '.js':
                    contentType = 'text/javascript';
                    break;
                case '.css':
                    contentType = 'text/css';
                    break;
                case '.json':
                    contentType = 'application/json';
                    break;
                case '.png':
                    contentType = 'image/png';
                    break;
                case '.jpg':
                    contentType = 'image/jpg';
                    break;
                case '.wav':
                    contentType = 'audio/wav';
                    break;
                case ".mp3":
                    contentType = 'autio/mpeg3';
                    break;
            }
            fs.readFile(filePath, function (error, content) {
                if (error) {
                    if (error.code == 'ENOENT') {
                        fs.readFile('./404.html', function (error, content) {
                            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': contentType});
                            response.end(content, 'utf-8');
                        });
                    } else {
                        response.writeHead(500);
                        response.end('Sorry, check with the site admin for error: ' + error.code + ' ..\n');
                        response.end();
                    }
                } else {
                    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': contentType});
                    response.end(content, 'utf-8');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
server.listen(80);
console.log("Server running");
```

Comment: I think the app directory is just wherever you ran "npm install express --save" from, no?

Answer (score 1):

The app folder is whatever directory you decide to build your application in. All the code for the project will "live" inside that folder. For example, if I'm starting a project I want to call "Foobar", I'll start by creating a Foobar folder:

```
mkdir foobar
cd foobar
```

Now that you've moved into the folder (`cd`), you can install express:

```
npm install express
```

This will create a folder named `node_modules` inside `foobar` and install express inside that folder. If you look inside `foobar/node_modules`, you'll see another folder named `express`. All of express is in there.

I don't use Netbeans, so I can help you with that part, but the path to the express Node module itself will be `./foobar/node_modules/express/index.js'

Comment: thanks man, appreciate the help! But in the end i decided to do things the normal way I do and avoided a framework. Built my own little static file server and it works a treat :)! and i feel good for it! But I did manage to install express thanks to your answer and it works!

Comment: @AWonderfulMachineYes nice! I like it! :) I'd appreciate if you could mark my answer as correct!